# How do I throw and catch exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to learn exception handling for basic java programs. I read online and in a text book, and even practised the exercise my book gave me, yet I still don't have a good grasp of it.

I was hoping I could post my code below and see if anyone could tell me a better way to handle exceptions, or if I was even doing it properly.

```
public class labBookFortyTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int size = 0;

        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of grades there are ");
        size = myInput.nextInt();

        double grade = 0;

        double[] myArray = new double[size];

        TestScoresTwo myScore = new TestScoresTwo(myArray, size);

        for (int count = 0; count < myArray.length; count++) {

            System.out.println("enter grade ");

            grade = myInput.nextDouble();

            myArray[count] = grade;

            System.out.println("you entered " + myArray[count]);

        }

        double avg = myScore.avgGrade();
        System.out.println("avg is \t " + avg);
    }

}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class TestScoresTwo {

    int size = 0;
    double[] tScore = new double[size];
    double sum = 0;

    public TestScoresTwo(double[] scores, int sizE) {
        // double[] tScore = scores; //this line messed me up
        // the below line works
        tScore = scores;
        size = sizE;
    }

    public double avgGrade() {

        try {
            for (int otherCount = 0; otherCount < size; otherCount++) {
                if (tScore[otherCount] < 0 || tScore[otherCount] > 100) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("At the " 
                        + (otherCount + 1) + "   position "
                            + tScore[otherCount] + " is a wrong input ");
                }
            }

            for (int count = 0; count < tScore.length; count++) {
                sum = tScore[count] + sum;
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        double avg = sum / size;
        return avg;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should format your code so it's more readable if you'd like help.

Comment: to throw an exception and catch it doesn't really make a sense

Comment: Im sorry, i am not a very good coder, im trying to learn and when i got to the exceptions chapter i didnt understand much.

Answer (score 1):

So far, one answer and one comment have told you that its "useless" or it "does not make sense" to throw and catch an exception "in the same place."

Here's what they're really trying to tell you:  If a `throw new FoobarException(...);` is lexically enclosed within a `try {...} catch (FoobarException ex) { ... }` block, that's a sign that your code is poorly organized.  It would be cleaner to move the code that does the throw into a separate method.

The excellent book, *Clean Code:...* by Robert C. Martin ([http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)) advocates for the Single Responsibility Principle---the idea that each method in a program should be responsible for doing just one thing.

He explicitly says that handling an exception is *one thing.*  So, if you write a method that catches an exception, your code will be cleaner† if the corresponding throw happens in some other method that the first method calls.

```
private R reallyDoSomething(A a, B b, C c) throws SomeException {
    ...
    ... just worry about the normal case, and...
    if (something's not normal) {
        throw new SomeException(...);
    }
    ...
}

public R doSomething(A a, B b, C c) {
    try {
        return reallyDoSomething(a, b, c);
    } catch (SomeException ex) {
        ...
        ...handle abnormal case...
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, remember that there's a reason why they call them "exceptions":  They should be exceptional (i.e., unusual).  Usually, when a method throws an exception, it means that the method could not do whatever the job is that it is *normally* supposed to do.

Exceptions allow us to separate the code that handles the abnormal conditions from the code that does the normal work.  That can make the normal case a *lot* easier to read.  (If you've never tried to read a big C function definition where error-handling is intermingled with normal-case handling throughout, then you may not be able to fully appreciate the beauty of exceptions.)

So, if the purpose is to separate normal from abnormal, you can embrace that in two ways:  (1) Put the handler for the abnormal case (the try/catch) in a separate method from the one that does the "normal" work, and (2) Don't use exceptions for "normal" things.  (i.e., think twice before throwing an exception that is *not* an error).

---

† When Uncle Bob says "clean", he means "easy to read"

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you do does not make sense, you should not throw and catch the exception in the same place (it's quite useless). I highly recommend you to read tutorials about exception handling. Using google you could find really well designed lessons on the subject. For exemple, [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/index.html) is one of the first result you can get.
What you should do would look more like this:

```
public class TestScoresTwo  {
    //...

    public double avgGrade() throws IllegalArgumentException{
        for( int otherCount = 0; otherCount < size;otherCount++ ){
            if(tScore[otherCount] < 0 || tScore[otherCount] > 100){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("At the " + (otherCount + 1) + "   position " + tScore[otherCount] + " is a wrong input ");
            }
        }
        for(int count = 0; count < tScore.length ; count++) {
            sum = tScore[count] + sum;
        }

        double avg = sum / size;
        return avg;
    }
}
```

And you supposed to catch your exception when calling the method that throws the excpetion.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
// ...
    try{
        double avg = myScore.avgGrade();
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`throw` here doesnot makes much sense I think you should throw an exception when there is nothing you can do to get out of your current state.

Moreover If you are catching an exception, you do not need to `throw` it, unless you are going to `rethrow` it.
Something like this

```
try{
}
catch (Exception e){
     throw new customException(e);
}
```